# Reference only digested files

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have some folders (of static assets) from which I take some groups of images. With [`Path.wildcard/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Path.html#wildcard/2) everything works wonderfully, but problems arise when I digest for production, then I find that all the images get duplicated.

How do I take one group (digested only) or the other (non digested)?

Comment: Define “digested” and how they differ from “not-digested.”

Comment: in the phoenix environment, "digested" means that the file is suffixed its 32-chars digest, like the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the name of a digested file has the form `app-8e93c8da27a19b82af2ba9d653edb2cb.js` and a non-digested file is named `app.js`, this code will split all js/css files in the current directory in two lists of digested and non-digested filenames:

```
Path.wildcard("*.{js,css}")
|> Enum.split_with(fn filename -> Regex.match?(~r/^.+\-[0-9a-f]{32}\..+$/, filename) end)
|> IO.inspect

# {["app-8e93c8da27a19b82af2ba9d653edb2cb.js"], ["app.js"]}
```

Alter the `Path.wildcard` argument to your needs.